# Etsy Authentication changes

Tags: authentication, oauth, postman, etsy

I am working on Etsy Authentication. I have created an app and tried to test the Authentication via Postman in the same above process but I was not able to Authenticate I was getting an error
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoOzx.png)

And I was unable to Edit the App  and also there is no option of **"Request Full Access"**

[No Edit option and also no Request full access and the app state is in pending approval](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIvvK.png)

Help me with the issue as I was previously able to Edit the App and I have tested few APIs as well but now I am unable to do it.

Postman image
[If I hit this API in the browser as a response I need code but I was getting the above error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfXUW.png)

Comment: Have you omitted the Client ID from your screenshot or are you just not passing one?

Answer (score 1):

Your request isn't working because you haven't registered the callback URL for postman with your App, and of course you mentioned that you couldn't edit your app to add the callback URL.

There is a silly URL bug on the Etsy dev portal which sending you to a broken like when you click on your app to edit it.

Once you click on the App to edit it and end up at the 404 page,
[Remove this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAmDB.png) from the URL and it will then work.

I have emailed the Etsy Developers to point out this bug so hopefully it will be resolved quickly.

Comment: I cannot find the area or field where I could edit the callback URL. Not even at this link https://www.etsy.com/developers/your-apps I can access the keys but there is no option to add or edit the callback URL. Can it be issue when I created the app or is there any other issue?

Answer (score 0):

To piggyback off of Gareth's answer:

**Step 1:**
In [https://www.etsy.com/developers/edit/{account_id}/callbacks](https://www.etsy.com/developers/edit/%7Baccount_id%7D/callbacks), add the following callback:

```
http://localhost:3003/oauth/redirect
```

**Step 2:**
Follow these instructions https://developer.etsy.com/documentation/essentials/authentication/, make sure to set:

```
redirect_uri=http://localhost:3003/oauth/redirect
```

*You don't actually need anything running at localhost:3003